# How to make dynamic or update name on Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there any way to update/change org.eclipse.ui.views extension point's view name from java side ?

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
   <category
        id="my.ui"
        name="My app name">
   </category>
   <view
        category="my.ui"
        class="com.ui.control.ControlView"
        id="my.ui.controlView"
        inject="true"
        icon="icons/icon.ico"
        name="Dynamic Name"> --this part i want to update from java side
   </view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally do this in the `ViewPart` class (`com.ui.control.ControlView` in your example) by calling the `setPartName` method:

```
protected void setPartName(String partName)
```

The default value for the name is taken directly from the `name` field in the `IConfigurationElement` for the extension point so it can't be changed (see `org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart#setInitializationData`)